# Modify Perl script to run for each file with specified extension in a given directory

Tags: perl

I need to modify a Perl script `x937.pl` to run on all files with extension `.x937` within a specific directory. Currently, I use a separate script `test.pl` that calls my main script, and runs it for each file of that type. However, I need to combine both into one script.

Ideally, I would be able to specify a directory path in the script, and loop through all `*.x937` files in that directory.

**test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Encode;

my @files = <*.x937>;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    system('x937.pl', $file);
}
```

**x937.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Encode;
use warnings;

my $tiff_flag = 0;
my $count     = 0;
my $file      = "output_$ARGV[0].txt";

unless ( open OPUT, '>' . $file ) {
    die "Unable to create $file";
}

open FILE, '<:raw', $ARGV[0] or die "Error opening '$ARGV[0]' $!";
binmode( FILE ) or die 'Error setting binary mode on input file';

while ( read( FILE, $_, 4 ) ) {
    my $rec_len = unpack( "N", $_ );
    die "Bad record length: $rec_len" unless ( $rec_len > 0 );
    read( FILE, $_, $rec_len );
    if ( substr( $_, 0, 2 ) eq "\xF5\xF2" ) {
        if ( $tiff_flag ) {
            $count++;
            open( TIFF, '>', 'output_' . $ARGV[0] . '_img' . sprintf( "%04d", $count ) . '.tiff' )
                    or die "Can't create image file $!";
            binmode( TIFF ) or die 'Error setting binary mode on image file';
            print TIFF substr( $_, 117 );
            close TIFF;
        }
        $_ = substr( $_, 0, 117 );
    }
    print OPUT decode( 'cp1047', $_ ) . "\n";
}
close FILE;

close OPUT;
```

Comment: Look up the "sub" command in perl.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html

Comment: Looks like you have the core elements there - you just need to 'wrap' your second script in the foreach loop.

Comment: @Jason: Your `x937.pl` program has a few problems. Most seriously `$tiff_flag` is never modified after it is initialised to zero, so the `if` block is never entered and no TIFF files are created. That means the `$tiff_flag` and `$count` variables can be deleted. There is also no need for the first `binmode` as the open mode is `<:raw`,

Comment: Everyone, thank you very much for your help! Very sorry I have not responded until now - was sick yesterday. Maintaining $tiff_flag for future ability to extract Tiff files from x9-37 Image Cash Letter file. Currently not being used, but may be in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to generate this correctly (on iPad, sat on the sofa) ... There could be some typos `; )`

Usage: `perl test_x397.pl <path>`

test_x397.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; use warnings;
use Encode;

my ($path) = @ARGV;
$path // die "No path specified";
(-e $path) or die "Path not found: $path";
(-d $path) or die "Not a directory: $path";

my @files = <$path/*.x937>;

foreach my $file (@files) {
   process($file);
}

sub process {
    my ($fname) = @_;

    my ($dir, $file) = $fname =~ m{^(.*)/(.+)$};

    my $tiff_flag = 0;
    my $count = 0;
    my $outfile = sprintf("%s/output_%s.txt", $dir, $file);

    open (my $outfh, '>', $outfile) or die "Unable to create $outfile. $!";

    open (my $infh, '<:raw', $file) or die "Error opening '$file'. $!";


    my $buffer = undef;

    while (read ($infh,$buffer,4)) {
        my $rec_len = unpack("N", $buffer);
        die "Bad record length: $rec_len" unless ($rec_len > 0);
        read ($infh, $buffer, $rec_len);

        if (substr($buffer, 0, 2) eq "\xF5\xF2") {
            if ($tiff_flag) {
                $count++;
                my $tiff_filename = sprintf('%s/output_%s_img%04d.tiff', $dir, $file, $count);
                open (my $tiffh, '>', $tiff_filename) or die "Can't create image file $!";
                binmode($tiffh) or die 'Error setting binary mode on image file';
                print $tiffh substr($buffer, 117);
                close $tiffh;
            }
            $buffer = substr($buffer, 0, 117);
        }
        print $outfh decode ('cp1047', $buffer) . "\n";
    }
    close $infh;
    close $outfh;
}
```

A few things to note:

1. Always use the three argument version of open
2. Using a scalar filehandle makes it easier to pass it around (not necessary in this example but good practice)
3. Don't modify $_. It can lead to nasty surprises in larger programs
4. You already used sprintf to make part of your tiff filename, so why not use it for the whole thing.

Comment: Your `$outfh` is scoped to the `unless` block, and doesn't exist at the point of the `print` and `close`. It worked for the OP because he used a global file handle. It's best to stick to the popular idiom `open my $outfh, '>', $outfile or die "Unable to create $outfile: $!"` or `use autodie`

Comment: What is `$tiff_flag` - is it set outside the program somehow?

Comment: Just noticed Borodin pointed out the same thing in a comment on the OP - the question still stands :)

Comment: Why is everyone getting so hung up on a flag? There were more fundamental things goi on that needed sorting first

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *“more fundamental things*, but the behaviour of `$tiff_flag` renders a big chunk (the whole of the inner `if`) of the `while` loop ineffective. So your tinkering with the code in there is pointless. If you're referring to the points you raise in your answer then, while they are valid, none of them prevent the code from working.

Comment: @DavidK-J This looks very good. I added '(' in
`open (my $outfh, '>', $outfile) or die "Unable to create $outfile";`
I believe this is correct.

However, it's dying on that line. If I comment out the `open $outfh` and `close $outfh`, and remove `$outfh` from the `print $outfh decode etc` line, then everything will print successfully to screen.

Any suggestions? I feel this is probably basic, but sadly, my understanding is not quite there.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permission to write to that directory?
I updated my code to replace the mysteriously disappeared bracket, and also to add `$!` to the `die` output. Running again /should/ shed some light on what's going on there.

Comment: I failed to mention that I am running in Windows.
I changed `my @files = <$path/*.x937>;` to `my @files = <$path\*.x937>;`.
I hope the omission of my OS has not caused any confusion.

I ran
    C:\TMP> perl test_x937.pl C:\TMP\
and received following error:
`Unable to create output_C:\TMP\200000004_20150129_000954_69001.x937.txt. Invalid argument at test_x937.pl line 23.`

I think `$outfile` contains full path - I'm currently trying to research and correct, but any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: pretty sure you keep it as a forward slash, but I can't test that right now ;)

Comment: Leaving forward slash returns the following error:  
`Unable to create output_C:\TMP\/200000004_20150129_000954_69001.x937.txt. Invalid argument at test_x937.pl line 23.`  
Think filename vs path is currently the main issue. I'll let you know if I get it figured out.

Comment: Updated again, untested (no Windows here). Might need some fiddling.

Comment: @DavidK-J One minor change and it works perfectly:  
change `$file` to `$fname` in `open (my $infh, '<:raw', $file) or die "Error opening '$file'. $!";`  Thank you for all your help!